# Any connections between mixed model and mixture of experts model?

Tags: mixed-model, infinite-mixture-model

Given data $<y_i, X_i>$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, \dots n\}$ ($n$ samples), and we are interested in knowning the relationship between $y$ and $X$. In the simplest manner, we can solve for $\beta$ where:
$$
y = X\beta + \epsilon
$$
Soving $\beta$ by minimizing some loss (e.g. $\ell_2$ loss) will give us an overall understanding of $\beta$.

However, more than often, the data have some heterogeneity, and we also have several solutions to deal with them:

1) [Mixture of Expert](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/csc321/notes/lec15.pdf): 
$$
y = \sum_i^kp_kX\beta_k+\epsilon
$$
where $k$ stands for the number of experts and $p$ is the probability, and estimating $p_i$ and $\beta_i$ is the challenge.

2) [Mixed Model](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/introduction-to-generalized-linear-mixed-models/):
$$
y = X\beta + \epsilon_i + \epsilon
$$
where $\epsilon_i$ stands for the residue error left due to heterogeneity (i.e. random effects). And the challenge is to estimating $\epsilon_i$

It seems to me that these two differs in the sense that whether you want to treat the heterogeneity as the fixed effect or random effect. I wonder if there are deeper connections other than hand-waving arguments.

I wonder if there are any works connecting and discussing these two methods, like some arguments about advantages v.s. disadvantages.

**Edit:** Thanks for @[Machine epsilon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/17760/machine-epsilon) pointing a related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310064/mixture-models-vs-mixed-models). But I hope my question could raise a deeper discussion of the relation of these two, instead of an introduction of the differences of these two, like the answers to the related question. Additionally, to raise a deeper discussion, to understand what [random effect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode) is will also be related in my opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixture models vs Mixed models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310064/mixture-models-vs-mixed-models)

Comment: @Machineepsilon Thanks. But I'm hoping for a deeper discussion of these methods. As you can see, my original question already contains the information in the answers of that link. :-)

Comment: Well, the two are simply two fundamentally different models. It's hard to understand what you are looking for. It's kind of asking for the difference between an ice cream cone and a helicopter.

Comment: The short answer is "no".  Unfortunately, the longer answer is also "no".