# linear mixed effect model with symmetrical heavy tailed errors distribution

Tags: r, mixed-model, modeling, heavy-tailed

I am using the `Lmer` function from the `lmerTest` in `R` to test the significant of fixed effects [Training (2 levels factor: H/GD) & Value (2 levels factor:D/ND)] on  % of responses (numeric: ResTest), with a repeated mesures design (20 subjects tested in the 4 conditions: H/D, H/ND, GD/D, GD/ND = 4 observation / subject).

Here is my model, with Subject as a random factor:

```
mymodel <- lmer(ResTest~Value + Training + Value:Training + (1|Subject), data = Data)
```

This what the summary gives me:

[image: my model summary]

Residuals are symmetrical, all fixed effects are significant.

Using the `r.squaredGLMM(mymodel)` I obtained the R2 for the model, which is 0.9873067.

I then run diagnostics of my model, first checking for the normality of my residuals, using `qqnorm(residuals(mymodel), ylab="Residuals for mymodel")` & `qqline(residuals(mymodel))` . That is what I get and where problems begins: my residuals are heavy tailed.

[image: QQ plot]

Plus, when I plot the residuals vs fitted, there is some large y axis data point and data point don't tend to cluster towards the middle of the plot at all. But I mean, my data are like this, with two of the conditions inducing almost always 100 % of responses and the 2 others inducing near 0% of responses and nothing in the middle.

[image: residuals vs fitted]

I tried to asses the impact of some of my data point with `plot(cooks.distance(mymodel))` to see if there is something here, but it's seems that no data point have an excessive influence on my model.

[image: cooks distance]

With all of this, I am not sure how I can trust my model (and the very good R squared) and I really would like to improve it (and understand it). Have I gone in a completely bad direction ?

Also, is there a reason why I should use `lmer` instead of `lme` ? Because I have seen this `heavy` package, with the `heavyLme` fonction ("This function fits a linear mixed-effects model under heavy-tailed errors using the formulation described in Pinheiro et al. (2001)").

So I tried my model like this:

```
model <- lme(ResTest~Value + Training, random = ~1|Subject, data = Data)
```

and obtained same results.

I tried to do the heavyLme fonction, but it didn't work because I don't get what is this "groups" argument...

```
mymodelheavy <- heavyLme(ResTest~Value + Training + Value*Training ,
                         random = ~Subject, groups = ~ ?,  data = Data)
```

Here is the density graph of my dependent variable (% of responses), using     plot(density(Data$ResTest)).

[image: outcome density]

and here is a plot density of the residuals of my lmer model (plot(density(residuals(mymodel)): [image: residual density]

I hope someone can help me with all of this.

**EDIT:
My data are binomial and I should not have done lmer in the first place, but glmer with family=binomial and a logit link. Works much better that way !**

Comment: I don't trust that r-squared value at all. Can you post an image of the kernal density plot of your outcome? `plot(density(x))` You should also check out `robustlmm` and `heavy`. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustlmm/vignettes/rlmer.pdf It goes through the different options for heavy-tailed distributions.

Comment: I tried the heavyLme (see in the end of my post) but I don't get the groups argument, could you help on that ? I see that the robustlm package have to do with sensibility for outliers, but I don't think this is the problem here as cook distance didn't show anything ? Any way, I tried the rlmer fonction like this: `mymodel<-rlmer(ResTest~Value + Training + Value:Training + (1|Subject), data = Data)` and don't really get the results :/... I posted the density graph on the post. Thanks !

Comment: That histogram says it all. You do not have a unimodal distribution. `lm` and `lmer` and their offshoots are designed to model unimodal distributions or 0/1, count, rates, etc. You have a bimodal distribution, which could could be a mixture of two normal distributions. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310064/mixture-models-vs-mixed-models for a start.

Comment: So if I get it, what I really want would be a "mixed effect mixture mode"l... is there some formula do to that, like for lmer ? I saw some stuff like FLXMRlmer, but I don't understand a thing about it... lmer already was complicated for me :/

Comment: The residuals plot density shows that the distribution is not binomial (see post), so should I still do a mixted effect mixture model?

Comment: The q-q plot shows that you have major issues with the residuals from a linear model. That, combined with the density plot of your outcome, suggest that you need a different approach. I do not know much about multilevel mixture models, I'm afraid. The one program I know you can estimate them in is Mplus, but that is not freeware. There is a student version you can play with that limits you to seven variables, I think.