# Correct statistics technique for prob below

Tags: r, business-intelligence

I am kind-of stuck with a small problem here. I can't find a proper statistics based technique which will solve my problem!

**Problem**: I have a dependent variable (Categorical 4 Levels), and 6 Independent variables (all Categorical). I am trying to find out rules which will tell me how my dependent variable is getting affected by independent variables.

Eg: Say my dependent is ***Time*** which has 4 levels - Morning, Afternoon, Evening and Night. 
My Independent are, say 3  variables - **Gender** (Male/Female), **SalaryBin** (Bin1, Bin2, Bin3, Bin4) and **Dept** (IT, Marketing, Ops).

I want to **just understand and NOT predict** what kind of people come to office at a particular time. My results can be in form - Morning :- 75% Female, Bin2&Bin3 ,IT ; Afternoon:- 55% Male, Marketing Bin1 & Bin4.

Now the techinques i have tried include : RF and DT (CHAID using rPart in R).
Would be great if someone could just point me toward the right technique for the above problem. I can take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you haven't really given any code I too am not going to provide any as I feel your question is more for the information & techniques behind it.

When creating models such as random forests it can be hard to actually visualise what is going on under the hood but a good starting point would be to compute a feature importance plot.

You can achieve this by using the function `varImp(rfModel)`.

Another good way of visualising the model is to create some partial dependence plots as seen below.

[image]

The y axis is the models response and the x is the value (usually sampled from its minimum to its maximum). These plots are neat when trying to understand how different values impact your models outcome.

I can't speak directly for random forests but I use this a lot when visualising interactions with neural networks. It's quite nice to be able to hold the other inputs at a constant value (which can be adjusted usually by creating a matrix). Being able to change these constant values allows you to create different profiles in your model.

> > E.g. I wonder how age effects the models outcome for males who smoke.

The above can easily be answered with such plots.

Anyway, I hope this has helped out in some way but please feel free to comment if you feel it necessary.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datarobot/vignettes/PartialDependence.html

In the case that partial dependence plots are a right fit for your use case, I think this package may be of use: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdp/pdp.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to predict the outcome, you should use a standard **contingency table** for your issue. After that you could may use some Chi-Squared Tests for independence, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As alredy noticed by Nico Shabadoo, what you need is probably just a simple contingency table. If you want to extract *meaningful groups* from your data, you may use one of the methods for clustering, e.g. [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering), or [latent class analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122213/latent-class-analysis-vs-cluster-analysis-differences-in-inferences/134346#134346). If you wanted interpretable model that would enable you also to make predictions, you could try using a some kind of [decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) (you would predict time by using other variables).